# Inherit void method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I want to know how can I override a void method from the super class:

```java
public class Father
{
    public void showName(String name){
        System.out.println("My name is :"name);
    }
}

public class Children extends Father
{
    public void showName(String name)
    {
        super.showName()+System.out.println("my name is: "+name);
    }
}
```

`super.showName()+System.out.println("my name is: "+name);`
I know this command won't compile, but still how can I override this void method?

Comment: Use ```@override``` above ```public void showName(String name)``` in the ```Children``` class.

Comment: What do you want to do? What showName method should do? Display father's name? Display chldren's name?

Comment: By redeclaring the method in the subclass you **are** overriding the method.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: yes, you can. remove the `+` part and everything will work

Comment: @NirLevy no it doenst work..

Comment: @PavelMolchanov i want to create an object of the children's class and print  the father's name and the children's name at the same time using the "Name" method of the children class, instead of creating 2 objects of 2 classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override a method that has a `void` return type just like any other method, you just can't use its super's return value, since it doesn't have one. E.g.:

```java
public class Children extends Father {

    @Override
    public void showName(String name) {
        super.showName(name);
        System.out.println("my name is: " + name);
    }
}
```

Having said that, this is a pretty questionable design, and it would probably make more sense to have a method that takes that `name` parameter and builds a string from it, leaving the actual printing to the caller.